# Finding matches in multiple columns of mysql with an array set of data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pattern-matching

I have a PHP array: `Array(keyword1,blah0,blah1,blah2)` and an SQL query.

In the query I want to find if one of the data in Array exists in one of the few columns selected `(columnA|columnB|columnC)` and fetch that row if true.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. I couldn't tell if you wanted to check every column for every value in your array.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE columnA = $phpArray[0] OR
columnA = $phpArray[0] OR
columnB = $phpArray[0] OR
columnC = $phpArray[0] OR
columnA = $phpArray[1] OR
columnB = $phpArray[1] OR
columnC = $phpArray[1] OR
columnA = $phpArray[2] OR
columnB = $phpArray[2] OR
columnC = $phpArray[2] OR 
... 
columnC = $phpArray[n];
```

You can use PHP to create this statement in a loop

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ";
for($i=0;$i<count(phpArray)-1;$i++){
   $sql .= "columnA = "+"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+ OR "
   $sql .= "columnB = +"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+ OR "
   $sql .= "columnC = +"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+ OR "
}
$sql .= "columnA = +"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+ OR "
$sql .= "columnB = +"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+ OR "
$sql .= "columnC = +"'"+$phpArray[$i]+"'"+;"
*send sql query
```

**edit:** Fixed errors in code

Comment: +1 because this will work, but 32bitfloat's answer using SQL's `IN` is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I made a couple of mistakes anyway. Didn't know about `IN` statements, so I learned something out of this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a query like this:

```
$instring = implode("','", $array);
$sql = "SELECT `xy` FROM `z` WHERE (`columnA` IN ('".$instring."')
OR `columnB` IN ('".$instring."')
OR `columnC` IN ('".$instring."'))";
```